Approximating $\#\{\pi \in S_n:\exists k,\pi(k)=k,~k\leq m\}$
Consider the permutations from $S_n$ and let
$$
K(n,m)=\#\{\pi \in S_n:\exists k,\pi(k)=k,~k\leq m\}
$$
be the number of such permutations which have a fixed point in the first $m$ positions. I am interested in $N(n,m)=n!-K(n,m).$ By inclusion-exclusion, we have
$$
N(n,m)=\sum_{i=0}^m (-1)^{i}\binom{m}{i}(n-i)!.
$$
When $m=n,$ in the case of Derangements, we have the approximation
$$
N(n,n)\sim n!e^{-1}
$$
to the number of such permutations, obtained by partial summing the Taylor series for the exponential.
There should be a similar approach to approximate $N(n,m)$ but I can't see it. I am particularly interested in $m=n^\theta,$ say $\theta \in (0,1/2),$ as well as $m=\log n,$ perhaps by some optimization of the remainder in the Taylor series for $e^x$ around $x=-1.$

Isn't $N(n,m)=\sum_{i=\color{red}0}^m (-1)^{\color{red}i}\binom{m}{i}(n-i)!$? It would agree with $!n = n! \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \frac{1}{i!}$ for $m = n$ then.

While a random model won't give the exact answer, it's probably pretty reliable for the general size. There are $m$ chances of having a fixed point, each with probability $\frac1n$. If we model that by independent random variables, then the probability of having no fixed point is $(1-\frac1n)^m \approx e^{-m/n}$, and so we would expect $N(n,m) \approx n!e^{-m/n}$. When $m/n = o(1)$ this is approximately $n!(1-\frac mn) = n!-m(n-1)!$.

TLDR: $N(n,n^\theta) \sim n! e^{-\frac{1}{n^{1-\theta}}}$ and $N(n, \ln{n}) \sim n! n^{-\frac{1}{n}}$ as $n\to\infty$, which seems to be true from numerical comparison (e.g. in Desmos). However, it's obtained from a quick hand-waving derivation, but I'm sure that a rigorous proof exists.
First, observe that
$
\frac{1}{n!} N(n,m) = \sum_{i=0}^m \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} \frac{m!}{(m-i)!} \frac{(n-i)!}{n!}.
$
Hand-waving step 1: as both $n\to\infty$ and $m\to\infty$, for each $i$ it holds that $\frac{(n-i)!}{n!} \sim \frac{1}{n^i}$ and $\frac{m!}{(m-i)!} \sim m^i$, so $\frac{1}{n!} N(n,m)$ is "equivalent" to $\sum_{i=0}^m \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} \left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^i$.
Hand-waving step 2: for large $m$ (and hence large $n$), the latter sum is "equivalent" to $e^{-m/n}$, which leads to $e^{-\frac{1}{n^{1-\theta}}}$ and $ e^{-\frac{\ln{n}}{n}} = n^{-\frac{1}{n}}$.

UPD. Here is some intuition for why this approach gives quite accurate asymptotics. It's a well-known fact that
$$
\left|e^{-x} - \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} x^i\right|\leq \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!},
$$
so when $x$ is close to $0$, $e^{-x}$ can be approximated with only a few terms of series. As $\frac{m}{n} \to 0$ for $m = n^\theta$ and $m = \ln n$, we can assume that $\frac{m}{n}$ is as small as we need. In other words, we don't really need to think of a large number of terms in the sum for $\frac{1}{n!}N(n,m)$ -- instead, we can assume that $n$ is large enough for terms with, e.g., $i \geq 2$ or $i \geq 3$, to have negligible contribution to the whole sum. In this case, the actual chain of approximations looks more like
$$
\frac{1}{N!}N(n,m) \sim 1 - \frac{m}{n} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m(m-1)}{n(n-1)} \sim 1 - \frac{m}{n} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{m^2}{n^2} \sim e^{-m/n}.
$$

$$N(n,m)=\sum_{i=1}^m (-1)^{i+1}\binom{m}{i}(n-i)!$$
Going from the binomial coefficient to the gamma function
$$\binom{m}{i}(n-i)!=\frac{\Gamma (m+1)\,\, \Gamma
   (-i+n+1)}{\Gamma (i+1)\,\, \Gamma(-i+m+1)}$$ leads to
$$N(n,m)= n!\,\, \Big(1-\, _1F_1(-m;-n;-1)\Big)$$ where appears  Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function.
As other users already answered and/or commented, for large values of $n$
$$N(n,\log(n))\sim n!\, \big(1-n^{-1/n}\big)$$
Working in the real domain, using $n=e^k$, consider
$$f(k)=\frac{N\left(e^k,k\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(e^k+1\right)}=1-\, _1F_1\left(-k;-e^k;-1\right)$$ and
$$g(k)=1-\left(e^k\right)^{-e^{-k}}$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \large\frac {f(k)}{g(k)} \\
 5 & 1.0032362269966601900 \\
 10 & 1.0000226862248399823 \\
 15 & 1.0000001529501854996 \\
 20 & 1.0000000010305767510 \\
 25 & 1.0000000000069439719 \\
 30 & 1.0000000000000467881 \\
 35 & 1.0000000000000003153 \\
 40 & 1.0000000000000000021 \\
 45 & 1.0000000000000000000 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
